# Looking for sci-fi series spells put onto paper or stone

Tags: story-identification, magic

Looking for sci-fi series spells put onto paper or stone. I know the beginning of the first book the son, who is the main character, mother and father are running from some bad people. The father stays back to hold them off and dies, the mother uses a spell to watch like a paper butterfly?? Later on the son is in school learning how to do this spell stuff and most of the student can't use paper but have to use stone or wood to put the spells on.

EDIT: Few years maybe so fairly new. Don't recall the cover art but the beginning takes place exactly like described.

EDIT: The protagonist would write spells on paper and use them to secure doors.

Comment: Can you add any details like cover art, when you read it, how old it might be...?

Comment: So, the spells are written onto the materials, or the materials are somehow imbued with the spell?

Comment: Written on the material and it is mentioned that using paper is harder than stone or wood.

Comment: "begging" = "beginning"?